# Restore Previous value when another element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have multiple elements each element is a tile, every element has text in it and when the user clicks on each tile it changes the text. I have one JavaScript function which handles this and it works but I would like to make it so that only one tile can have the changed text at a time. When the next element is clicked the previous should return to the default text. Below is my code. The text in the P tag is the default text.

```
 <div class="page" title="Page 2" onClick="changeText('Some text blah blah blah.','home-grid-one-one')">
    <p>Understandable</p>
  <div class="page" title="Page 2" onClick="changeText('Some different text blah blah blah.','home-grid-one-two')">
    <p>Measurable</p>

function changeText(text, ele) {
    var display = document.getElementById(ele);
    display.style.textAlign = "center";
    display.style.fontSize = "1em";
    display.innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: Your elements have no `id`s and your `onclick`s are just sort of hanging there.

Comment: Your code is a little bit messy, can you paste proper code with onClick inside some element rather than keep it in the air?

Comment: @Andy the second argument in the changeText function is the element ID and the onclick method is inside the element. It currently works but I am able to change the text in every element but I would like only one to be active at a time

Comment: @pavon147 ok thank you I have now updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I would like to suggest a simple solution. **Usage of data attributes.**

Tiles:

```
<p class='tile' data-default="The default text 1 here" data-clicked="Text to be replaced">The default text 1 here</p>

<p class='tile' data-default="The default text 2 here" data-clicked="Text to be replaced">The default text 2 here</p>

<p class='tile' data-default="The default text 3 here" data-clicked="Text to be replaced">The default text 3 here</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.tile').click(function(e) { // when the tile is clicked
    $('.tile').not(this).text($(this).attr('data-default')); // Except the clicked tile all are restored to default data
    $(this).text($(this).attr('data-clicked')); // The clicked tile gets the replacer text
});
```

If your replacer text contains HTML in it, use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: Exactly the answer I was typing up.

Comment: @Andy I have used this but every time I click on the first p tag it will change the text but show the data-default value of the first p tag in the second p tag